# How to permanently switch ruby -v 1.8.7 to 1.9.3

Tags: ruby, rvm

By using these commands

```
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
rvm use 1.9.3 --default
```

The version in current session is 1.9.3 but when I close terminal and reopen ruby version comes back to 1.8.7.

Do I need to add something to the .bash_profile ?

**Edit:** I found the another way is when I reopen terminal everytime just type source .bash_profile. The version then is 1.9.3. Is there anyway to execute the .bash_profile permanently ?

Comment: `rvm use --default 1.9.3` always worked for me.

Comment: It works as well for me but when close the terminal the version comes back 1.8.7. That seems weird

Comment: When you reopen the terminal, what does `rvm info` outputs?

Comment: The output shows ruby-1.9.3-p327 beautifully. But when I ruby -v, the version is still ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [universal-darwin12.0]

Comment: What about `which ruby` then?

Comment: the output is /usr/bin/ruby

Comment: http://shitgeist.blogspot.fi/2012/05/hell-is-color-of-ruby-rvm-installation.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes you need to add something to your bash profile. See here:
https://rvm.io/rvm/basics/

Quote:

> The rvm installation documentation instructs you to put the following line at the very end of your bash profile:

```
# This loads RVM into a shell session
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

Comment: @ChuMai - Are you sure that line is being executed? Is your shell actually `bash`? Please add it to the end of your `.bashrc` instead. Also try to run that line on your command-line and check that it is actually executing the `rvm` script.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file named `.rvmrc` with the text `rvm use 1.9.3 --default`.

Answer (score 0):

We're treading into sysadmin waters here but one possible explanation might be because of how you're logging into your shell and your OS. See the discussion of what files are loaded by your shell [here](http://hayne.net/MacDev/Notes/unixFAQ.html#shellStartup) and what makes up a login vs. non-login shell [here](http://hayne.net/MacDev/Notes/unixFAQ.html#loginShell).